# Adding window resize to my Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building my photography portfolio and want to use a horizontal continuous slider on large screens but have the images stack on smaller mobile devices. I'm trying to get my javascript to ONLY implement after the defined screen size of 768px. I have managed to do this using the code below but for these changes to take effect the browser needs to be reloaded each time, and I want these changes to happen as the browser re-sizes instead.

```
< script >
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $(function () {
        $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
        $(".post").wrap("<td></td>");
        $("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
} < /script>
```

I can get this to work exactly as I'd like by adding this script afterwards.

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        location.reload();
});
```

But this is a messy solution and the browser strobes as the window is resizing due to the continuous reloads. How can I combine the 2 pieces of javascript? to make a better solution...

Html including quick basic styling below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DGP Portfolio</title>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
body { 
    font-size: 62.5%; 
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
}
.box{ 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.first{ 
    margin-top: 80px;
}
.image {
    width: 100%;
}
h1 {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    width: 320px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 30px 0 0 -160px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
h1 {
    width: 530px;
    margin: 60px 0 0 -265px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
tr { 
    vertical-align: top;
}
.box{ 
    position: relative;
    width: 80vw;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.first{ 
    margin-top: 150px;
}}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
.image {
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 800px;
}
.box{ 
    width: 800px;
}}
</style>
<!--HELP HERE PLEASE - HOW SHOULD THIS BE RE WRITTEN ????-->
<!--HELP HERE PLEASE - HOW SHOULD THIS BE RE WRITTEN ????-->
<!--HELP HERE PLEASE - HOW SHOULD THIS BE RE WRITTEN ????-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script>
        if ( $(window).width() > 768) {      
            $(function(){ $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>"); $(".box").wrap("<td></td>"); $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
            event.preventDefault(); });   
    });
}
</script>
<!--HELP HERE PLEASE - WITHOUT NEEDING THIS ????-->
<!--HELP HERE PLEASE - WITHOUT NEEDING THIS ????-->
<!--HELP HERE PLEASE - WITHOUT NEEDING THIS ????-->
<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        location.reload();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>DAN GOLDSMITH PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <div class="box first">
            <img class="image" src="img/red1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img class="image" src="img/green2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img class="image" src="img/purple3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img class="image" src="img/red1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img class="image" src="img/green2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img class="image" src="img/purple3.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sur `< script >` is working, please be careful to use tags correctly like `<script>`

Comment: Sorry space on script was just a typo

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining your function and then adding an event listener to the window. This way you can call your function on load, resize, and even scroll if you'd like:

```
function doStuff() {
   if ($(window).width() > 768) {
      $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
      $(".post").wrap("<td></td>");
      $("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
          this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
          event.preventDefault();
      });
   };
});

window.addEventListener("load", doStuff);
window.addEventListener("resize", doStuff);
window.addEventListener("scroll", doStuff);
```

Comment: I tried to implement your code but couldn't get it to work. I've just put the html in the original text. If you use that and have 3 pics labeled, red1.jpg, green2.jpg & purple3.jpg all sized 1200px sq. for now you'll better understand what i'm thing to achieve with this code - it does work like this but I know the javascript is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Only execute the script when `> 768` is right reached (so before it was <= 768) with something like this:

```
<script>
    var before = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() > 768 && before <= 768) {
            //$("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
            //$(".post").wrap("<td></td>");
            //$("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
            //    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
            //    event.preventDefault();
            //});
            alert('> 768px reached');
        }
        before = $(window).width();
    }
</script>
```

JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/r578nbfj/1/

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I tried to implement your code but couldn't get it to work. I've just put the html in the original text. If you use that and have 3 pics labeled, red1.jpg, green2.jpg & purple3.jpg all sized 1200px sq. for now you'll better understand what i'm thing to achieve with this code - it does work like this but I know the javascript is a mess.

Comment: I edited my answer with a fiddle, it is working when you resize it ! Please try, it is working for the question you asked about resizing screen.